# delegate return value

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm having trouble returning a value to a delegate.

```
@protocol DataDelegateImage
- (void)failImage;
- (NSData*)successImage;
@end

@property (nonatomic, strong) id <DataDelegateImage> delegateImage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData* d;
```

And I call my delegates like:

```
[self.delegateImage failImage];
```

But now I'm trying to call the success delegate returning the data content, but I think I got something wrong, because the code doesn't work.

```
[self.delegateImage successImage:self.d];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your passing `self.d` to your `successImage` and there is no parameter for you to pass anything to it. If you want to be able to pass something to it then it should be like this

```
     - (void)successImage:(NSMutableData*)para1;
```

or

```
     - (void)successImage:(NSData*)para1;
```

unless you want something to be returned as well as passing something to it in which cases use

```
     - (NSData*)successImage:(NSData*)para1;
```

The `type` in the brackets `- (NSData*)` is the return type it should be, this is the type of `object` that you want to return from the method. Then your method name `successImage` then you would have the parameters `:(NSData*)para1` you can add more parameters as well

```
     - (NSData*)successImage:(NSData*)para1 withAString:(NSString*)para2;
```

the `type` inside the brackets of `:(NSData*)para1` parameters is the object type it takes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It took me a while to get my head round it.

Comment: I feel the syntax is the coolest part once you get to know about it.

Comment: @PraveenS I don't really have any issues now, but when I was learning it was a mind bender. +1 as your answer is simple and straight to the point.

Comment: Yup same was the case with me as i was doing C programming before taking it up. +1 as you have not left anything uncovered.

Answer (score 3):

Change `- (NSData*)successImage;` to `-(void)successImage:(NSData*)data;`

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration

```
- (NSData*)successImage;
```

declares a method that has no parameters and returns a value of type `NSData`. Judging by the calling code, it seems like what you really want is a method that takes one parameter of type `NSData` and returns nothing in particular. This can be achieved by the following declaration:

```
- (void) successImage: (NSData *) data;
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to set or send data to delegateImage you may do it as @praveen-s says

if you want to get data from the delegate you probably want to do this:

```
self.d = [[self.delegateImage successImage]mutableCopy];
```

Comment: I think what he means if you wanted to take the returned data from `-(NSData*)successImage;` and copy it into self.d, but I don't think you want the method to return anything you want to give the method a parameter. I think @BoteRock has just miss read the question.